# Use beego orm to create table automatic

Tags: mysql, database, orm, beego

Now I create a table to record users information，and for every user, I will create a table to record their behavioral record when they register in my website. How I can achieve this, what I do is create a table(the table name is userid_behavioral) when a new user register in my website.

Answer (score -2):

You should use gorm library for achieving this. Because it has useful callbacks.

http://doc.gorm.io/callbacks.html

Gorm has a callback for certain event. You can use AfterCreate callback.

Comment: consider adding details